# Why the version of apt show 'XXX' and apt policy 'XXX' is display difference?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am checking one package version, finding these two commands display difference version.

e.g.

`apt show A`:

```
Version: 1.0
```

`apt policy A`:

```
Installed: 0.9
Candidate: 1.0
```

Then, which version is belonged to package A?
Whether I need configure something?

Comment: Please provide a real, working example.

Comment: I'd use `apt-cache policy` to view all details of what is available; my preference for viewing what I think you're asking for, but sorry it's rather unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know the version of A, 0.9 or 1.0?
Why apt show displays 1.0 but apt policy is 0.9?

Comment: Provide your OS & release & full pastes of what you see...  If you were using my release for example (*chances are you're not but I can adjust for whatever release you're using once it's known*) we can explore the output you're seeing & tell you why you're seeing it.. but currently we have no OS/release nor package details to look up.  If you're asking what I think you're asking; `apt-cache policy` shows the clearest detail in understand what I think you're being confused by; but without package I can't explore what you're actually seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction in the different results of `apt show A` and `apt policy A` .

The `Version: 1.0` output of `apt show A` shows that the latest version of the A package in the Ubuntu repositories that is currently installable is 1.0. The `Installed: 0.9 Candidate: 1.0` output of `apt policy A` shows that version 0.9 of the A package is currently installed, but it is not the latest version according to the results of `apt show A`. To update the A package to the latest version run `sudo apt install A`

Comment: Thanks. you mean the display of 'apt show A' is not mean the currently version? It should latest version in useable?

Comment: `apt show A` shows the latest version of A that is currently installable, for example with `sudo apt install A`

Comment: Thanks. I used to think this command is mean that the currently version in system.